# Proof of $x! > (x/2)^{x/2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone help me to prove this inequality?

> Prove: $ x! > \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^\frac{x}{2}$ where $x > 0$.

Note: found this inequality when proving Lagrange's form of the remainder.

Comment: I'd guess you'd start by rewriting $x!$ using the gamma function.

Comment: yes, thank you so much, i get it now. really helpful.

Comment: Is $x$ an integer? Normally, when you write $x!$ instead of the Gamma function you are implicitly assuming that it is

Comment: thank you! @Gary